# Place Logo between Map and Markers in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, maps

I have a web application with a full-page Leaflet map and a static logo on top as shown in the snippet below.

With this implementation, the logo floats above all map elements. For the actual application, it would be better to place the logo between the map and the markers on the map. In this way, the logo would not hide the markers when panning the map.

What I tried so far:

- Simply modifying `z-index` does not work, because Leaflet groups tiles, markers and other map elements in a single `div`.
- I also played with [Panes](https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/) and was able to place the logo on a custom pane between map and markers. But in this way, the logo is not static any more as it moves with the map.

```js
var map = L.map("map");
L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", { attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' }).addTo(map);
L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
map.setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#logo {
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 500;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 50%;
  color: #255c99;
  background-color: #7ea3cc;
  border: 2px solid #255c99;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="map">
  <div id="logo">Logo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't be done. You seem to have done a good deal of research on the issue, and have already discovered that Leaflet groups all panes in the same [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) - and it's not possible to interleave an external block (i.e. outside that stacking context) between two blocks of a stacking context.

Comment: @IvanSanchez: I was already afraid that it was not possible. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Ivan Sanchez in the comments, placing a static logo between map and markers is not possible in Leaflet.

The only solution I could think of is to place the logo in a [Pane](https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/) and compensate the zooming and panning of the map with JavaScript. But I guess that would be quite wobbly.